# Windows Authentication in MVC5 intranet web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

trying to do something really basic!

I have an MVC5 Web app - and I want to make it work as an intranet app. I had a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322(VS.98).aspx  and it seems straightforward .  I want to things a little different though .. I want to control access by roles in a global way .. I would have thought through web.config.

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
<allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

So - we have 2 servers , 1 Domain Controller SBS2008 and 1 web server Windows 2012 server which is connected to the SBS domain .

1) I can log on to app ok if I am a domain administrator
2) I can deny myself access using those settings in web.config.

The problem is whenever a standard user tries to go to the site they are asked for a user name and password.  Help!

One other thing - I can't enable impersonation or I get Error 500 .

Comment: How are you testing the standard user login? From the web server itself, or from a domain connected client machine? There are many things that might be involved here - browser, server, etc.  What auth headers do you see when you inspect the traffic?

Comment: Testing from a domain connected Client machine - and the web server it is connecting to is not the domain controller but it is connected to the controller.  I can get the users connecting no problems if I make them an administrator on the server ( as opposed to just a user ) - but that doesn't seem to be an ideal solution!

Comment: I recall having this issue when the permissions on the website folder where too restrictive - I either had to add the IIS application pool account or domain users to the folder permissions.